# What kind of encoding is this? - apple, int, hex

Tags: encoding

Trying to figure out how to alter some preset files and wonder how to decode my values to match this encoding ... its used in a preset file of an apple music sequencer

appears as (int), hex representation (2bytes)

```
     b1 b2  |  b1,b2(i) b1b2(i) b2,b1(i) b2b1(i)
0    00 00  |  0,0      0       0,0      0
1    80 3f  |  128,63   32831   63,128   16256
2    00 40  |  0,64     64      64,0     16384
3    40 40  |  64,64    16448   64,64    16448
4    80 40  |  128,64   32832   64,128   16512
5    a0 40  |  160,64   41024   64,160   16544
6    c0 40  |  192,64   49216   64,192   16576
7    e0 40  |  224,64   57408   64,224   16608
8    00 41  |  0,65     65      65,0     16640
9    10 41  |  16,65    4161    65,16    16656
10   20 41  |  32,65    8257    65,32    16672
11   30 41  |  48,65    12353   65,48    16688
20   a0 41  |  160,65   41025   65,160   16800
21   a8 41  |  168,65   43073   65,168   16808
40   20 42  |  32,66    8258    66,32    16928
50   48 42  |  72,66    18498   66,72    16968
100  c8 42  |  200,66   51266   66,200   17096
200  48 43  |  72,67    18499   67,72    17224
```

Can't stand the logic behind this, help much appreciated - tyia!

Comment: Pretty unclear what you're trying to do... if it is a mapping table, and you _got_ the table, then what is the problem?

Comment: so if you want to represent 112 or 149 what would you write in the hex field? its not a mapping table --- just saved few values to figure it out ... :o)

Comment: You could just experiment and see what you get for each one.

Comment: seems like its reverse byte order, now i need a formula to get to the desired value. one part of it should be 65536